# Error #1064 in MySQL syntax

Tags: mysql, case

I wrote one sql case condition query for view of mysql but I got error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;error at AS `total_amount_paid`, at line 3
```

The following is my code:

```
create or replace ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_customer_payment_status` AS select `p`.`customer_id` AS `customer_id`,
concat(`l`.`first_name`,'',`l`.`last_name`) AS `customer_name`,
sum(CASE WHEN l.lead_id = p.customer_id THEN`p`.`payment_amount`) AS `total_amount_paid`,
sum(CASE WHEN l.lead_id = c.customer_id THEN `c`.`pending`) AS `total_amount_due`,
(sum(`p`.`payment_amount`) - sum(`c`.`pending`)) AS `difference`,
if(((sum(`p`.`payment_amount`) - sum(`c`.`pending`)) > 0),0,1) AS `status` 
from ((`tbl_leads` `l` join `tbl_customer_payments` `p`) 
join `tbl_customer_payment_schedule` `c` 
on((`l`.`lead_id` = `p`.`customer_id`)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add END CASE to your CASE statements.  Right before the close parenthesis.

```
sum(CASE WHEN l.lead_id = p.customer_id THEN`p`.`payment_amount` END CASE) AS `total_amount_paid`,
sum(CASE WHEN l.lead_id = c.customer_id THEN `c`.`pending` END CASE) AS `total_amount_due`,
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?  You may need to add an ELSE statement before END CASE. Like `ELSE 0 END CASE` so that the sum function has something to sum at all times.